# Python: putting rows data from a csv file into a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, csv

I have a CSV file in the same directory as my Python script, and I would like to take that data and turn it into a list that I can use later. I would prefer to use Python's CSV module. After reading the the module's documentation and questions regarding it, I have still not found any help.

#### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
inputfile = 'inputfile.csv'

inputm = []

reader = csv.reader(inputfile)

for row in reader:
    inputm.append(row)
```

#### inputfile.csv

```
point1,point2,point3,point4
0,1,4,1 
0,1,1,1 
0,1,4,1 
0,1,0,0
0,1,2,1 
0,0,0,0 
0,0,0,0 
0,1,3,1 
0,1,4,1
```

It only returns the string of the filename I provide it.

`[['i'], ['n'], ['p'], ['u'], ['t'], ['f'], ['i'], ['l'], ['e']]`

I would like it to return each row of the CSV file as a sub-list instead of each letter of the filename as a sub-list.

Comment: can you share the contents of your csv

Comment: point1,point2,point3,point4
    0,1,4,1
    0,1,1,1
    0,1,4,1
    0,1,0,00,1,2,1
    0,0,0,0
    0,0,0,0
    0,1,3,1
    0,1,4,1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the file in read mode, read the contents!
That is,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
inputfile = 'inputfile.csv'

inputm = []

with open(inputfile, "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        inputm.append(row)
```

Output:

```
[['point1,point2,point3,point4'], ['0,1,4,1'], ['0,1,1,1'], ['0,1,4,1'], ['0,1,0,0'], ['0,1,2,1'], ['0,0,0,0'], ['0,0,0,0'], ['0,1,3,1'], ['0,1,4,1']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to `open()` the file:

```
inputfile = open('inputfile.csv')
```

You may want to look at the `with` statement:

```
with open('inputfile.csv') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    inputm = list(reader)
```